# qemu user networking: forward non-localhost guest IPs to the host

Tags: networking, routing, qemu

I'm running a qemu VM in `user` networking mode and I'd like to be able to access forwarded ports from the host. Something like the following works well.

```
-netdev user,id=t0,hostfwd=tcp::9992-:9992
```

But my VM makes an internal bridge network and I'd like to be able to access IPs from within that network. According to the [documentation](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#Advanced_user_networking_options), the following should work but there's definitely something missing

```
-netdev user,id=t0,hostfwd=tcp:10.144.0.2:6868-10.144.0.2:6868
```

After adding a network alias for `virbr0` or `lo` (`sudo ifconfig virbr0 add 10.144.0.2`) that host and port may respond to the `netcat` utility, but I'm having trouble contacting the services on the other side.

Is what I'm attempting possible? Here's my full invocation:

```
/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 \
-smp 1 \
-m 1024 \
-uuid 6780dc39-da5f-4dda-844c-59f81b1a3c4c \
-pidfile cfdev-efi-state/qemu.pid \
-enable-kvm \
-machine q35,accel=kvm:tcg \
-object rng-random,id=rng0,filename=/dev/urandom \
-device virtio-rng-pci,rng=rng0 \
-drive file=cfdev-efi-state/disk.img,format=qcow2,index=0,media=disk \
-boot d \
-cdrom cfdev-efi.iso \
-drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=/usr/share/ovmf/OVMF.fd \
-device virtio-net-pci,netdev=t0,mac=52:7a:c1:64:44:26 \
-netdev user,id=t0,hostfwd=tcp::9992-:9992,hostfwd=tcp::9999-:9999,hostfwd=tcp:10.144.0.2:25555-10.144.0.2:25555,hostfwd=tcp:10.144.0.2:8844-10.144.0.2:8844,hostfwd=tcp:10.144.0.2:8443-10.144.0.2:8443,hostfwd=tcp:10.144.0.2:6868-10.144.0.2:6868 \
-nographic
```